# C++ access DLL load

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have a DLL plugin to connect two different external application. Long story short, application A calls my plugin by exposed function, then my plugin calls application B (also by exposed functions) and return values from B to A.

Application A has a config file in which I have to specify a path to my DLL plugin. Then it loads the DLL and calls it. Unfortunately application A has no ability to load more than one DLL. Is it possible to write a custom code inside of the plugin to load some additional DLLs when it's loaded? In other words, I would like to always load application B DLLs when my plugin is load by any process.

Other solution would be to add the directory of the application B to the list of folders in which main process will be searching for DLLs, however I also don't know how to do this.

For now I added application B directory to the system path env variable but this is unacceptable solution.

Thanks

Comment: Pass the full path of the DLL to `LoadLibrary`. And/or use `SetDllDirectory` or `AddDllDirectory` to influence DLL search.

Comment: This would resolve my problem but the only question is: where should I call the SetDllDirectory? Can I call it on plugin DLL load?

Comment: You need to call it before you call `LoadLibrary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me that you need to modify the [DLL search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx). Use `SetDllDirectory` or `AddDllDirectory` to do that.

Alternatively, you may be able to meet your requirements simply by passing the full path to the DLL when you call `LoadLibrary`. This will likely work well provided that the DLL you load doesn't have any dependencies that are contained in your application directory structure.

Comment: SetDllDirectory allows me to load DLLs dynamically. Is there a way to load them implicitly?

Comment: Plugins are loaded dynamically. If you want to load DLLs implicitly, then they become part of the application rather than plugins. Place the DLLs in the same folder as the executable in that case.

Comment: I just found an msdn article about "DllMain entry point" / "Initialization routine for the DLL". I hope I'll be able to combine it somehow with SetDllDirectory you mentioned.

Comment: I don't really know what you are looking for here.  You said, "Other solution would be to add the directory of the application B to the list of folders in which main process will be searching for DLLs, however I also don't know how to do this." Do you want to do that or not?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to add application B location to the search path used to locate DLLs or if not possible, load DLLs one by one when my plugin is loaded by system.

Comment: Yes you did, however SetDllDirectory doesn't work with static global variables (which I need to have in order to cash data). Is there a way to let linker know to load not only plugin, but all of the DLLs from the plugin path?

Comment: I attempted to answer the question you asked. It's frustrating for the question to change and for you to supply extra constraints in comments. If you want to ask a new question, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Are the DLLs created by you? If you are creating the DLLs then I would suggest you to create static libraries instead of DLLs and then using this static libraries you can create one DLL which will contain all the symbols you need.

Comment: What do you mean by "create on DLL using the other DLLs"?

Comment: I have edited my question. Could you please check again?

Comment: Unfortunately the only DLL I create is plugin.

Comment: Then you can create a wrapper of the DLLs and make static libs from them, after doing this you can create your own DLL. Though it can be complex depending on your program architecture.

Comment: Can you check this link - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/63f28d08-6924-4813-bfa5-7ad6c37dc74c

Comment: I can't do this. The DLLs need to stay as there are.